# Change select box value text

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I got one text box and one select box.

```
<input type="text" />

<select>
<option value=1>Test1</option>
<option value=2>Test2</option>
</select>
```

Now i want when user type anything in text box, to change value=2 text.

I tried this, but looks like don't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#textbox").keyup(function () {




    $("select#sync[value='2']").text($(this).val());
});
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you haven't given the elements IDs, the problem is that you need to access the `<option>` element (that one has a value of `2` - there is no `<select value=2>`). Also, IDs are unique, so using `select#sync` is (should be) the same as `#sync`:

```
$("#sync option[value='2']")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<select>
   <option value="1">Test1</option>
   <option value="2">Test2</option>
</select>​
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textbox").keyup(function() {
       $("select option[value='2']").text($(this).val());
    });​
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gxaWE/

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$("#sync").val($(this).val());
```

provided that the user only types the value that is in range

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dneh8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#text_box").keyup(function() {
 $("#sync option[value='2']").text($(this).val());
});
```

​
    ​

Here is fiddle showing it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/bRw8Z/1/

It changes select option number 2 text. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems here:

1. It doesn't make sense to set the `innerText` of a `<select>` element; you want to set its value instead,
2. The `#textbox` selector wouldn't actually select anything.
3. If your input did not exactly match an `<option>`'s `value` attribute, the first `<option>` would be selected.

This snippet will select an `<option>` if its `value` attribute matches the value of the text input.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").keyup(function () {
        var $select = $("select"),
            value = $(this).val();
        if($select.find('option[value="' + value + '"]').length){
            $select.val(value);
        }
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2XxRQ/1/